# Android app to send and receive a file automatically when get connected via bluetooth

Tags: android

I am new to android world.I want to design an android app in which all connections will be through bluetooth. It will works as follows
as I click some button like start it will connect to one of the paired devices(mobile) and get a file, store it somewhere and eventually disconnect with that device.Then it will connect to the second device, get a file, store it and then disconnect with that device and so on. It will repeat the same procedure for all the paired devices.
And later on I will replace those paired mobiles with sensors and will collect the the data.The whole process should be automatic without user's intervention.
Guys please help me. Is it possible for a mobile to send a file automatically as it connects to a particular mobile.

Comment: Did you try writing any code whatsoever?

Comment: Yes I have just started coding for this project and tried to connect the devices automatically without using onClicklistener.